# React javascript "Error: Credential is missing" when connecting to DynamoDBClient

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I'm trying to connect to my dynamoDB table from inside a React js app. I have AWS credentials set up locally. When I run my app, I get the following error on Chrome Devtools: "Error: Credential is missing".

Oddly, if I run the AWS example found below using pretty much the same code via node on terminal, it works fine. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/dynamodb/src/partiQL_examples/src/partiql_getItem.js

To run the AWS example, I created a new mjs file inside my react SRC folder, so it should have all the same access as the React app, right? No credentials are explicitly added in the mjs file or the react app.

Why doesn't the React environment have access to the credentials? I've tried both ~/.aws/credentials and environment variables. The AWS SDK seems to say that it should just work for Node. Any thoughts?

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ExecuteStatementCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';


function App() {  
  const dynamoDB = new DynamoDBClient({ region : "us-west-2"});

  async function loadFromCloud () {    
    const command = new ExecuteStatementCommand({
      Statement: `select * from TableX`
    });
    try {
      const data = await dynamoDB.send(command);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your client initialization code.

Comment: Sure, done. Still getting used the appropriate amount to share...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have **`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`** and **`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`** specified as environment variables and that you also specify **`AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`**

However, your React app is run in the browser. It should only work in a `node.js` app.

Comment: As noted in my question, I tried the environment variables already. I didn't know about AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG, but that didn't help either. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This approach works with node.js. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html) you can find how to make it work directly from the browser, which is the case for your React app.

Comment: It is true. You're only building it with node, but it is running in the browser.